# Decision: ListView or ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I need an Android Activity, which should show a field like a headline with an image and several dynamic generated items (1 to 100 I think) below it.
If I would not want the headsection to scroll, I would use a LinearLayout and put the headsection layout in it. Below this, I would add a ListView for scrolling the items, but I want the headsection to be scrolled to, as a top of the list.
Should I just put the stuff in a ScrollView or is there a better idea?

Comment: Listview has an ``addHeader()`` method.

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself - you say that you don't want the header to scroll, but then you say that you want the header to be scrolled to...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I DO want the header to be scrolled. A view added with addHeader will not be scrolled, correct?

Comment: a view added to the listview' s ``addHeader()`` will be scrolled, not sticky in the top. jsut like a list item.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems that I misunderstood 'addheader()'. When it will be scrolled, it is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`should show a field like a headline with an image and several dynamic generated items (1 to 100 I think)` - use a ListView as it can recycle views (efficiency reason). Also, it's easier to change and maintain a list adapter than a complex UI structure.

`If I would not want the headsection to scroll, I would use a LinearLayout and put the headsection layout in it.` - Why not use a `RelativeLayout` that has the header on top and tha list occupies the rest of the height. This way you have the expected result.

`but I want the headsection to be scrolled to, as a top of the list` - then set the list header, or use different views in your listview and make your first item look different. More on this topic - search `android listview different views` in Google.

Either way to put it - use a `ListView`!

Comment: Ok, seems that a ListView with addHeader() will do it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a ScrollView with a LinearLayout as it's child, and put your stuff into the LinearLayout. Remember ScrollViews can only have one child layout. That should work fine. Something like this:

```
ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/aboutFormLinearLayout"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/aboutFormVersionDescription"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
              android:gravity="center"
                 android:singleLine="true"
              android:text ="Version: "
                 android:textSize="15sp"
              android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/aboutFormVersion"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor = "#000000"
                    android:layout_marginBottom ="20sp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/aboutFormCompanyDescription"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:textSize="15sp"
              android:text ="Company: "
              android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/aboutFormCompany"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor = "#000000"
                    android:layout_marginBottom ="20sp"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I agree, I hadn't thought about recycling the views. The other answer is better!